# two models in 2sls procedure

Tags: 2sls

I am trying to do following.
bysort Country: regress bdr fam MTB lnTA
this is my first stage regression for second stage I want to use another variable std as my dependent variable and use predicted value of bdr from first regression as independent variable. so second model will be like.
bysort Country: regress shtd Predict(bdr) fam MTB lnTA lnTA2(square)
for reference I am attaching a table from a Published Paper. Can anyone[image] help me how can i solve this?

Comment: You should revise this question to improve its clarity

Comment: how to use one model in first regression and another model in second stage regression. in first stage regression model is bdr fam MTB lnTA   and in second stage model is  std Predict(bdr) fam MTB lnTA. In second stage predict(bdr) which is estimated from first stage regression.